# Swift How to present view controller like Apple's calendar and Clock app?

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

Apple's built-in apps are always simple, succinct and elegant. Sadly, Apple is reluctant to give us all the code freely.
I'm struggling to make a presenting view controller in a elegant way like this:

[image]

[image]

My question is, when the plus button on the top right corner of the first view controller is pressed, the second view controller is presented.
The presented view controller has Cancel button and Add button, and the buttons are in a navigation bar.

But when I call method

```
self.navigationController?.presentViewController(myVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

the presented view controller has no button or navigation bar.

Comment: I mean the presenting view controller through the plus button

Comment: You mean using the standard `presentViewController:animated:completion:` method of `UIViewController`? Your question is getting down voted because it unclear and vague. Update it with more details about your actual issue.

Comment: You might want to take a look at these links: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/ https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/

Comment: You need to create a `UINavigationController` with `myVC` as its root view controller. Then you can create buttons by modifying `myVC`'s `navigationItem`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are missing the `Navigation Controller` to start with, when you add it, you could enjoy the benefits of the top navigation bar and Apple's features like back button and others.
In the storyboard drag and drop the Navigation Controller and make it `Storyboard Entry Point`.

Make it look something like:
[image]

Comment: thank you. the point is navigation controller.